# Given a Category $\mathcal{C}$, does the opposite category $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ always exist?

Tags: category-theory

Imagine we have a non-bijective epimorphism $f:A\to B$ between two objects of $\mathcal{C}$. Now, it seems that the "reversed arrow" $\bar{f}:B\to A$ is not well defined for al least one $x\in B$.

Because of this, it seems it is not possible to ``reverse'' happily some arrows in some categories and, thus, it seems that the opposite category $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ is not well defined or has less arrows than the original category. Is that correct?

Comment: $\mathcal C^{op}$ is well defined, but we can no longer interpret the arrows $\bar f$ as a function over a set while also interpreting the binary operation as composition

Comment: So far as I understand it, the opposite category is just a notational thing where the domain and codomain of the morphisms are switched so that it is not necessary to write 'contravariant' over and over again. For example, '$F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is contravariant' can be written as '$F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}$'

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but has been asked before: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092872/do-opposite-categories-always-exist?rq=1). The answer, briefly, is that opposite categories *do* always exist, but their morphisms need not 'mean' what we're used to morphisms meaning. You have to get away from the idea that "morphism from $A$ to $B$" means "function from the underlying set of $A$ to the underlying set of $B$" - objects need not have underlying sets at all, and even when they do morphisms need not "look functional" at all.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44768/maps-in-opposite-categories?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I think dropping the language of morphisms entirely may help demystify things. Say that a **partial monoid** is a pair $(A,*)$, where $A$ is a (nonempty, for simplicity) set and $*$ is a **partial** (= not always defined) binary operation on $A$ with the following properties (where "$\downarrow$" means "is defined"): $(1)$ if $x*(y*z)\downarrow$ then $(x*y)*z\downarrow=x*(y*z)$ (associativity); $(2)$ for each $a$ there are unique $b,c$ such that $(i)$ $b*b\downarrow$, $c*c\downarrow$, $a*b\downarrow$, and $c*a\downarrow$, $(ii)$ whenever $b*u\downarrow$ we have $b*u=u$ and [etc. etc.]. (contd)

Comment: (Intuitively $b$ and $c$ are the ids of the source and target objects of $a$.) Basically, the collection of morphisms in a category equipped with composition forms a partial monoid; and every partial monoid can be construed as a category. The "opposite category" is then no more mysterious than the "opposite partial monoid" $(A, *^{op})$, where $a*^{op}b$ is defined iff $b*a$ is defined and is equal to $b*a$ if the latter is defined. This is a purely algebraic idea, analogous to the **opposite *ring*** construction; only by thinking of morphisms as functions do we get into the conceptual weeds.

Answer (score 4):

A category $\mathcal C$ consists of a collection of objects $ob(\mathcal C)$ and a set $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in ob(\mathcal C)$.

Given a category $\mathcal C$ we can define the opposite category $\mathcal C^{op}$ by $ob(C) = ob(C^{op})$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C^{op}}(x,y) = \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(y,x)$

Note that the notation $f:x \rightarrow y$ does not in any way imply that $f$ is an honest to god function between $x$ and $y$. That notation only implies that $f \in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(x,y)$.

The set $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(x,y)$ can be whatever set you want, it can be the set $\{banana, apple, 2,3,x\}$.

As long as you define how all the morphisms compose anything is allowed.

Hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had missed the point that the set of morphisms do not need to be "good functions" or "significant morphisms". Now, everything is clear!